# Bootstrap Dropdown is not styled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working in a template with bootstrap 3, the dropdown menu looks really complicated and I do not understand.

```
        <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

That is my code I copy it from http://prntscr.com/2g8507 . My browser is empty, and don't know why. 0 errors at inspect element. The CSS file is connected and so is the js.

Comment: elaborate on "my browser is empty" and perhaps post a jsfiddle

Comment: with "browser empty" i meaned there is no dropdown there...

http://jsfiddle.net/35tuN/

Comment: that is "unstyled" not empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include css and js file and then you have to use proper structure.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rj8Nd/3/

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Also be careful to include jquery before bootstrap.js in your website.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you haven't loaded bootstrap, so it's not going to look pretty. It isn't displaying nicely, but I'm not sure what you mean by "browser empty"... It looks like this to me:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem i had when i forgot to include JQuery before bootstrap.js

Is Jquery included? Is it loaded before bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the class `sr-only` you'll see it. `sr-only` sets height/width to 1px and does some really strange hiding activity.